# Sci Fi horror movie title (probably mid-70s). Astronauts attacked by giant one-eyed alien with death ray

Tags: story-identification

There were a few astronauts. Possibly 3, they went to space I think on a rescue mission of another crew. While in space, they saw the bodies of the other crew floating in space. They managed to fish one in that was still alive. But later it turned to attacked the crew. But I think they managed to overcome it.

Later this crew landed on a planet. On this planet, there was this giant one eye alien with long legs that shot out death ray. They looked kinda like War of the World aliens. One crew was zapped and disintegrated.

Finally, one crew sacrificed himself by walking into this large white sphere like object. As he walked in, he became a skeleton and the sphere was destroyed. I think the remaining one crew managed to escape.

Comment: [Journey to the 7th Planet?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bC-mQXrb4-4)

Comment: HI I read the plot outline but it is not the one.  Thank you for such a prompt response!

Comment: You might want to have a quick read of [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to see if you can come up with any more info

Comment: What did their spacesuits look like? Who were they rescuing? What was the likely budget of this film? Were they attacked by *multiple* separate baddies over the course of the film or was the floating astronaut monster linked to the eyeball monster in some way? What was the sphere and how did it relate to the eye monster? Why did walking into it destroy it?

Comment: I watched this as a boy and I totally do not understand the plot but some images remained in my mind.  So I actually could not answer all these questions Valorum :)

Comment: See confirmation comment from OP under answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it might be [**Mission Mars**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063311/) from 1968.

It has three astronauts, they travel to Mars on some kind of rescue mission, and there is a white sphere. Oh, and it does have a character played by Nick Adams who sacrifices himself, and the alien does sort of resemble the 'War of the Worlds' Martian invaders.

I might as well post the entire movie, since it's available on Youtube.

Comment: A very good find. I'm not sure the value of putting the trailer (which doesn't show the memorable bits) as well as the entire film (which does), so I've removed it

Comment: I hope the new MST3K does this one, i don't know how i missed this movie as a kid

Comment: @Valorum, I posted the trailer in case the OP didn't have time to watch the whole movie, also the trailer showed the 'one-eyed alien', the sphere, and the man being attacked by the death ray. Oh well, I guess the OP could just skim through it anyway.

Comment: Hey this is correct.  Oh my goodness, thank you Valorum and the Guest!  I didnt know the title for decades!

Comment: Sean, can you please select this answer and also give it an upvote? I would much appreciate it and thank you. Glad I could help you find this.

Comment: How do I select this answer?

Comment: You click on the star symbol, or whatever symbol is there for you to click on next to the answer. I'm actually not sure, never posted a question on here but on movie stack exchange I think it's a check mark.

Comment: Thanks I just saw that check mark on the left hand side

Comment: just as a trivial, I posted a similar question on this at a certain forum 13 years ago and I could not get an answer.  But now 13 years later, I posted this here and I got the answer within a day.

Comment: I've only been a member of this site for two years, so it was perfect timing. I'm glad you found it because I searched for it as well for many years. I think it's great that we can now see super obscure movies like this on the internet.

Comment: You mean you were looking for this movie for a long time or were you searching for its title too like me?  Have you watched this movie before?

Comment: @168Sean168, I meant I had seen snippets of it on television when I was a little kid, but I never could remember what it was. Years later I found it, but can't remember where, probably in one of my many film reference books.

Comment: I see.  Thanks.  I watched it as a boy too, on a very small box tv.  The scene of people disintegrating and walking into the sphere haunted me.  Glad I have closure now